# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactEditText$InternalKeyListener.setInputType(int)' on a null object

Tags: react-native

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactEditText$InternalKeyListener.setInputType(int)' on a null object reference**

[image]

React Native version:
Run `react-native info` in your terminal and copy the results here.

```
system:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 4.02 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.13 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2021.06.07.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 27, 28, 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.1, 30.0.2, 30.0.3
      System Images: android-29 | Automotive with Play Store Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Android TV Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_265 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.10 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-native: 0.63.4 => 0.63.4
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Random error, yesterday before I shutdown my computer, the error appears.

I hope someone could help me with same problem.

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'

Comment: @HamidAlaei this not work on me :(

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'